# Replace a line 5 lines above current line in vi editor in ex mode

Tags: unix, vi

I want to replace a line that is 5 lines above the current line in the vi editor. 
It has to be a single command in the ex mode.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
:-5s/^.\*$/Your Replacement/
```

That should work, and will move the cursor to that line